# Assign Path for each link in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have multiple pdf documents that I have to show in a view .My code is opening the same document for all the links which is wrong.

In my contoller :

```
public ActionResult Docs()
{
    var docModel = this._documentBuilder.Build(this.StateData);
    foreach (var doc in docModel.OldEstimateFiles)
    {
        return this.File(doc.PdfUrl, "application/pdf");
    }
    return null;
}
```

and in the view :

```
foreach (var menuItem in Model.OldEstimateFiles)
{
    <ul >
        <li>
            @using (Html.Anchor(new ststyle { URL = "/DocumentEstimate/Docs", Target = "_blank", Text = menuItem.Label }))
            {
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

what is wrong in my code knowing that oldestimatefiles is a list

Comment: You have a `return` statement in your controller method (which immediately exists the exits the method in the first iteration and returns only the first file. You method needs a parameter to identify the file so that you return a specific file

Comment: That s great I agree but how to call it in the view in the anchor?

Comment: I have no idea what `Html.Anchor()` is - its not part of MVC. And how do you uniquely identify you files? Using the standard helper, it would be `@Html.ActionLink("displayName", "Docs", "controllerName", new { id = someIdentifier }, null)` and the method would be `public FileResult Docs(int ID)` and you then return the file based on the ID value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my action in the controller to take in the ID.

```
public ActionResult Docs(string id)
        {
            var docModel = this._documentBuilder.Build(this.StateData);
        return docModel.OldEstimateFiles.Any() ? this.File(docModel.OldEstimateFiles.Find(p => p.ID == id).PdfUrl, "application/pdf") : null;
        }
```

I added an entry in the routeConfig file taking in the URL the id of the document and In the view I edited my link :

```
 @using (Html.Anchor(new ststyle
              {
                  URL = "/DocumentEstimate/EstimateDocs/" + menuItem.ID,
                  Id = menuItem.ID
```

It resolved the issue.